# Why can't we directly change size or origin of a UIView frame?

Tags: objective-c, ios

It may sound very silly to people who know this but I am quite new to iOS.
I wanted to know, why cant we modify origin or size or may be x,y or height width of these properties of a UIView frame ?

frame is a CGRect struct and origin and size are again CGPoint and CGSize structures.
when we can access them, why cant we modify them ?

There is nothing like this in a CGRect, we can modify it's attributes so why cant we do  it for frame or bounds.

Comment: Great question, not silly at all!

Comment: @ChrisNolet: It's been more than two years since I posted this!

Comment: After 4 years of doing iOS, I finally understand why I can't set the frame directly!

Comment: The reason is he entire frame is writable/assignable while single properties not (only readble)

Comment: I wrote an extension in Swift that lets you set a views frame to any specified origin.  I did a little math and figured out where the center position needs to be in order to get the desired origin.   The extension technically still sets the center property (adjusted to get the desired origin) !   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012406/how-to-set-a-uiviews-origin-reference/65324896#65324896

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I assume you mean why can't you do somethIng like this:

```
myView.frame.origin.x = 23.0;
```

It's a good question, nothing silly about it. The problem is that the frame is held as the property of the view, not the individual components of the frame (the size and origin, or even deeper, the width, length, x and y).

The frame is fundamental to the view, so there are lots of actions that a view needs to do if its frame is modified. If you were to reach in and modify the origin.x directly then you would be bypassing the `setFrame` method where all of this magic probably happens.

When you access view.frame you are being given a CGRect that has the same value as view.frame, *but is not actually the frame*, so any modifications to it don't affect the view.

You can do it in  steps:

```
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 23.0;
view.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and not considering it silly. But I do feel silly after understanding it.
i hope anyone having a similar doubt will find this helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. OK, by `view.frame` we get a C struct that isn't the real `view.frame`. Isn't it simpler to just say we get a copy? OK, so we get a copy. Why need a copy anyway?

Comment: doesn't answer anything on why updating origin / size can't update the frame ?

Answer (score 10):

The answer lies in the (slightly obfuscated) language syntax:

1. `myView` is an Objective-C object.
2. So `myView.frame` is a property accessor method being send.
3. It returns a C struct of type CGRect.
4. `frame.origin.x = 1` modifies the returned temporary struct that is local to your code.

Your intent was to tell an object something by sending it a message. But instead you asked the object for data and then modified this data. The object would never now.

The compiler should warn you about this error.

Comment: Thanks for a clean simplified answer.